# Correcting color cast with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, colorfilter

I have two videos that have a pretty significant blue cast to them. I took some stills at the same time and I'm happy enough with the colors on those and I'd like to re-encode the videos, adjusting the colors to something similar to the stills.

- A frame from the original video can be seen here: http://www.dotrose.com/temp/img_20180513_153484_original.png
- An attempt at correcting the color, which would be acceptable: http://www.dotrose.com/temp/img_20180513_153484_corrected.png
- A still image taken at the same time (but with some help from a flash): http://www.dotrose.com/temp/img_20180513_153476.jpg

I understand I could either create a large collection of jpg images from the video and color correct them before reassembling them into a new video or I could use ffmpeg's color level's filter to do it directly. What I don't know is how to get the numbers to pass to the filter. I'm assuming I want to do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -vf "colorlevels=rimin=##/255:gimin=##/255:bimin=#/255:rimax=###/255:gimax=###/255:bimax=###/255, eq=gamma=#.##" -y out.mov
```

How do I get the values to use for each of the r, g, and b min and max settings and gamma to use in place of the ###s? Assuming this is the right approach, of course.

**Update**: Perhaps this question would be better asked in a forum for gimp or photoshop. But I know how to adjust the color in those. What I need to know is how I translate those changes to what ffmpeg is expecting.

Answer (score 15):

[image][image]

If you're familiar with using RGB curves you can use the [curves filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves). You can manually choose the curves values, but it may be challenging to color correct using numerical values. However, the filter accepts ACV preset files from Photoshop so you can do the correction there first, save the curves preset file, and then use it in the curves filter in `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "curves=psfile=color.acv" -c:a copy output
```

You can use the [`enable`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) option to correct certain scenes:

```
-vf "curves=psfile=interview.acv:enable='between(t,10,3*60)',curves=psfile=b-roll.acv:enable='between(t,200,236)'"
```

To get a screenshot for processing in Photoshop:

```
ffmpeg -ss 120 -i input -frames:v 1 output.png
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure I've asked the wrong question in the wrong place. Double whammy. I don't think trying to correct the color in ffmpeg is the right way to do this, so asking this of ffmpeg experts was liable to get no response. I've found a better way.

I used ffmpeg to extract all the frames (nearly 5,000 of them for my short videos). Then I used Photoshop to record an action, editing the color of one of those images. I then applied that action to all the files in a directory (File -> Scripts -> Image Processor) giving me color corrected images. Finally, I reassembled that set of images back into a video (using ffmpeg again). I'm working out how to do that properly so I get a clean video, but that's a totally different question to the one improperly asked here.